# Taking return type of a fuction as argument in python

Tags: python, function, arguments, return-type, dtype

I have come across gaussian_filter() function of Scipy.ndimage library of python which has its description as [Description](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter)

It says that we can pass an array or a dtype as an argument 'output' to this function and in case a dtype is passed then the function will return array of given dtype.

I am surprised and curious to know how the argument 'output' works here and how can I make my own functions with return types passed as an argument to those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check source code for the `gaussian_filter` function [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/ndimage/filters.py) and find out that for `output` it uses function `_get_output` from [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/ndimage/_ni_support.py). Check how it is built and you'll be able to make your own functions like this.